# How does telnet get through the windows firewall?

Tags: windows-7, windows, firewall, telnet, windows-firewall

I activated the Telnet client in Windows 7 and was instantly able to connect to servers although Windows Firewall is activated.

How does that work? Shouldn't the firewall block outgoing connections until I explicitly allow them?

Is a default firewall rule being created when you activate the telnet client in Win 7 and if so, which firewall rule should I look for?

I was unable to find any rule in my firewall for telnet.

Disclaimer: This is not really a problem I am trying to solve. I am just trying to understand how telnet is able to communicate without me opening the firewall for the program.

Comment: Windows firewall follows the same principals as NAT firewalls. it allows virtually any outbound connection, but only allows inbound packets that are part of a connection initiated from the inside.

Comment: Huh, why the downvote? Just because I misunderstood the outbound default behaviour?

Comment: wasn't me. perhaps they didn't like your disclaimer, but since they didn't leave a comment, no way to know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Outbound communications are generally allowed by default. However, if you were running a Telnet Server, inbound connections would be blocked by default. The exceptions would be if the installer for the Telnet Server opened the ports as a part of the install.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732283(WS.10).aspx

Answer (score 2):

The standard firewall in Windows does not block outbound connections. If you want to block the telnet client (or anything else with outbound connections) you can use the **Windows Firewall with Advanced Security** to set up outbound rules.